# CSS and HTML files we cant save

Tags: html, css

When you save a html or Css file in VSCODE, Content disappear and cursor goes to line 1 by erasing all the content in the file. Please I need help to save css and html files, On the Editor1.css type css code and when you press Command+ S on mac book, entire file which we type get erased off and cursor goes to line 1. and not able to save Css and Html files how can we save files on VS Code Editor

Comment: It's pretty staightforward, are you sure your document setting is UTF-8 ?

Comment: Yes It has been set to UTF-8 still not able to save files

Comment: Still did not work setup has been set to UTF-8 as well and i have uninstalled prettier and eslint as well did not work still looking for the solution if someone can help me please